# Querying all points within geography coordinates

Tags: sql, sql-server, bing-maps, latitude-longitude

Bing Maps is giving me bounding coordinates as opposite points on a box that looks like this:

```
'34.763402330018245,-76.65003395080568,34.692861148846255,-76.86890220642091'
```

In my SQL Query, I using that data to draw the box as a polygon in the clockwise direction, but not getting any data.  If I draw it counter-clockwise, I appear to get everything outside of the box.

```
SET @g = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((
34.763402330018245 -76.65003395080568,
34.692861148846255 -76.65003395080568,
34.692861148846255 -76.86890220642091,
34.763402330018245 -76.86890220642091,
34.763402330018245 -76.65003395080568))', 4326);
```

In my Where, I have `@g.STContains(geography::Point(p.Latitude, p.Longitude,4326 )) = 1`

Can someone tell my what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the Google Maps Javascript API v3?

Comment: it does in regard to the map providing the coordinates for the database to query and provide new points back to the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the problem!**

Because I am working with maps, I used the **geography** variable.  Apparently, that is the wrong way to do it.  You have to use the **geometry** variable instead.

My solution now looks like:

```
SET @g = geometry::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((
34.763402330018245 -76.65003395080568,
34.692861148846255 -76.65003395080568,
34.692861148846255 -76.86890220642091,
34.763402330018245 -76.86890220642091,
34.763402330018245 -76.65003395080568))', 4326);
```

And in the Where.....

```
 @g.STContains(geometry::Point(p.Latitude, p.Longitude,4326 )) = 1
```

Comment: Tried to mark this as the answer,  and got a message that I have to wait 24hours.  Really?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of the problem, you have a ring orientation problem. That is, whether you specify the points in a clockwise or counterclockwise fashion matters.

Try changing the order of the points (in your case swap the second and fourth I think) and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: No luck :(  See my comment below.

Comment: I'm actually in front of a computer now and it looks like your original polygon has the correct orientation. I wouldn't say that changing it to `geometry` is the right solution here as that's for planar geometry (which points on the Earth most certainly are not). Can you give an example point that you think should be in this polygon but SQL is saying it isn't?